# Removing Middle Names From String in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, text-extraction

I have searched this site for a solution and while there are many, many solutions for string handling, I didn't see anything like this.

If I have a middle name/names in the string, I want to remove it/them (e.g. 'Tommy Lee Jones' or 'Tommy Lee Brian Jones' becomes 'Tommy Jones', ).

Since the names could be of varying length, I assume that you would need to detect the white space either side of the middle names and then somehow create the new string with what was before and after the whitespace adding a space in between.  If it's only possible with 3 names, I would work with that.

Any solutions or even pointers in the right direction appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. start with the string ..
2. ... separate by spaces. this gives an array
3. get the length of the array.  example, say it is "3"
4. the first index is "zero". the last index is length-1.  in our example, the length is 3, so the last index is 2.
5. the firstname is the array[0]
6. the last name is the array[last index]

you're done!

this always works, with any number of names, even if only one name such as "Madonna".

be careful to check first that the input string is not blank.

Comment: If the input is `@"Madonna"`, your procedure would seem to give the result `"@Madonna Madonna"`.

Comment: Hi Maddy, correct but in fact (as you may know) it's absolutely impossible to use machine intelligence to fully parse any and all names in all languages and all name-style variants. Indeed, it's extremely hard to do that with a team of human staff on a support desk.  It's just a trivial beginner question: the OP does not know about things like arrays, splitting on spaces, etc!  So a good opportunity to learn about that stuff!

Comment: Hi Josh, that's correct - great isn't it?  It automatically solves that problem in the usual way.

Comment: @JoeBlow When you reply to someone, user their username preceded by the `@` symbol. Otherwise there is no notification. My comment was really meant for the OP so they realize what you pointed out in your first comment. This is a nearly impossible problem to get correct except for common, trivial names.

Comment: I'm confused, is it a trivial beginner question or absolutely impossible to give me what I was looking for?

Comment: Hi Lee, the simple solution is what I outline.  Go for it.  What maddy was saying is simply that, some people have unusual names.  Cheers

Comment: Hi Maddy - I never send notifications, it's just a QA site.  If it's incredibly important I add the @ notificationizer.  Cheers.

Comment: I agree with rmaddy. Spanish people are used to have a "double" family names. In France some have too... Even names with particules (De Something).  If it's "Junior/Jr at the end". The foundation of your question is too simplified.